# Is there a JET SQL condition clause to update only the Max Date records?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, jet-sql

I am using this Jet SQL Syntax,

```
UPDATE tbl1 
   INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.123 = tbl2.123 
   SET tbl1.a = tb2.b
```

For my condition to update only the max dates for table one I have used iterations of:

```
WHERE tbl1.123 IN (SELECT tbl1.123 FROM tbl1 GROUP BY tbl1.123 HAVING MAX(date));

HAVING MAX(date);
```

Is it not possible to make sure I am only updating the max date records in table 1?

I have duplicate records in table 1 and need to ensure that any new data from table 2 only gets attached to the most recent record and not the older duplicate values using JET SQL in Access. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
UPDATE tbl1 
   INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.123 = tbl2.123 
SET 
   tbl1.a = tb2.b
WHERE 
   tbl1.Date IN 
       (SELECT MAX(T.Date) 
       FROM tbl1 As T 
       WHERE T.123 = tbl1.123)
```

Comment: This worked - thank you. I guess explicitly making the connection in the subquery using WHERE helps it understand better?